# Show HTML url in pushpin title in Bing Maps V8

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps

I am using Bing Maps V8. I am unable to show a link (HTML url) in title of pushpin in bing maps. It instead shows the encoded HTML string in the title of pushpin.

I know that HTML elements can’t easily be rendered as pushpins in Bing Maps V8. But is there any solution to it? Right now my pushpin title looks like this in the image given below.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title property can only be text, not HTML. If you want the pushpin to be clickable, simple add a click event to the pushpin. Here is an example that opens up an infobox when a pushpin is clicked. https://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Infobox_MultiplePushpins You can do anything you want when the pushpin is clicked besides opening an infobox, and will have access to the pushpin that was clicked.